# Redrawing a view in IOS from outside the main thread

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have a (void) buttonClicked: (id) sender{} method.   After the user clicks the button, two changes to the gui are made, in this order:

1. Change A
2. Five second wait using [NSThread sleepFortimeInterval: 5]
3. Change B

Unfortunately, from inside the buttonClicked method, I can't seem to get the view refreshed after Change A, so that only Change B is visible upon exiting from the buttonClicked method.  I understand views can only be changed from within the main thread, and I've seen references to the  performSelectorOnMainThread method, but I can't figure how to call it, and how to refresh the view using it.

Comment: The documentation for [`performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) has links to sample code.

Comment: The simplest way would be pull the code that does the updates into their own function (eg, - (void)refreshView, and then call that from buttonClicked:, with [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(refreshView)]

Comment: Never put the main thread to sleep!